# Django with bootstrap4 and modal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-modal

Currently I am researching a project that has a form where some users can add their thoughts and other users can comment (the comments are divided in categories by user group in Django). I am facing a problem with not receiving the pk of the template and the django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user3_comment' with
 no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/comments/user3/(
?P\d+)/$'].
My model is like this:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    post_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class User3_comment(models.Model):
    commented_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True, related_name='user3_comment')
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
(some lines skipped)
```

forms.py
class User3_comment_form(forms.Form):

```
class Meta:
    model = User3_comment
    fields = ['comment','commented_post']
```

views.py

```
def user3_comment(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = User3_comment_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.commented_post = post
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = User3_comment_form()
    return render(request, 'myapp/user3_comment.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
url(r'^post/comments/user3/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.user3_comment, name='user3_comment')
```

post_detail.html
The post detail has a button:

```
{% if request.user|is_authorized:"user3" %}
<div class="modal fade" id="modal"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Add user3 comment</button>
{% endif %}
```

as well as modal code:

```
<script>
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var modal = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'user3_comment' pk=post.initial.id %}",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {
        modal.html(response);
    });
})
</script>
```

Problem is that I get a:
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user3_comment' with
 no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/comments/user3/(?P\d+)/$'] and I cannot seem to be able to debug it.
The modal itself works for I can get a static page to open when I link to it, but I cannot get the pk the ajax should be sending.

I use bootstrap4 for my app if that is relevant to the case.

**Update:**
I could not manage to sort the problem with function based views, so I switched to class based views and it solved the problem, for anyone interested in the solution, this is what I did:
I used the MultiFormsView (can be found in github https://gist.github.com/jamesbrobb/748c47f46b9bd224b07f) and created a MultiFormsView class:

```
class Post_Detail(MultiFormsView):
    template_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'
    form_classes = {'post': PostForm,
                            'user3_comment': User3CommentForm}

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': post.pk})

    def get_post_form_initial(self):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return { 'post_name': post.post_name, 
        'post_body': post.post_body, }

    def get_user3_comment_form_initial(self):
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
            comment = User3_Comment.objects.get(mark=post.pk)
            return {'comment_body': post.comment_body,}
        except User3_Comment.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Post_Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class User3_Comment(CreateView):
    model = User3_Comment 
    fields = ('post_body', )
    template_name = 'posts/user3_comments.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        postx = self.kwargs['pk']
        return {'post': postx}

    def form_valid(self, form):
#save logic
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: Regarding the post.initial.id, it is part of the template that has the detail view of the post: <form action="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.initial.id %}" method="POST" class="form"> {% csrf_token %}

Answer (score 0):

What's the `initial` field supposed to be? There's no mention of it. In any case you can try this:

```
{% with post.initial as initial %}
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'user3_comment' pk=initial.id %}",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {
        modal.html(response);
    });
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me, fully, the modal window gets called, but the id/pk is still not passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Per your error the argument you're passing in this line `url: "{% url 'user3_comment' pk=post.initial.id %}"` is empty.

In your view you're not actually passing `Post` as context to the page which could be why there is no value.

`return render(request, 'myapp/user3_comment.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})`

If you put `{{ post.initial.id }}` or any other `Post` field somewhere else on the page does it show a value? If not then your template tag is wrong. Based on your model it should be `{{ post.id }}`.

```
<button type="button" name="modal_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"
    value="{{ post.id }}" class="Modal">
</button>

$('button.Modal').click(function() {
    var post_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'user3_comment' pk=post_id %}",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {
        $('#modal').html(response);
    });
})
```

Comment: The {{post.initial.id}} does show a value, but the redirect still does not work. The {{post.id}} has never worked for me that is why I chose the {{post.initial.id}} route. That has always been the problem, I can get the post.id, but it never redirects to the comment page for the post.